# Setting up Version Control for Wordpress plugin development

Tags: plugin-development, version-control, workflow

Does anyone have suggestions for setting up version control for developing WordPress plugins? I'm working in a development environment, and I'm trying to avoid having to repo the entire WordPress instance. My ideal solution, is to create a repository for one individual directory that contains my plugin.

What are others using to manage their plugin development? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: If you're a sole contributor, you can use any SVN client, and your repository. on your local machine ( eg [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/). Otherwise use [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) for your repository.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz, it is always better to use github/bitbucket or whatever other service, if only to have a simple off-site backup for your code.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz  - so the best thing to do,  would be to change directory to my plugin folder, and then run 'git init' to create a new repository, and this repository would live separately from the rest of my development wordpress instance? Does that sound right?

Comment: @MarkKaplun, true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally set up a development environment as a base of my WordPress Development, where I've dummy data and some other [debugging plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/debug/). I then create my own plugin directory and do `git init` *in it*. During plugin development, I set up the [Developer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developer/) to *Plugin for a self-hosted WordPress installation*. It helps me to understand my plugin's performance with other plugins and themes.

Then I add my test data specific to that plugin, develop it, test it, finalize it - `git commit`.

For Git remote, I use Bitbucket and Gitlab for private plugins, and Github for public plugins.

When the plugin is ready to deploy, I then test it in other development environments similar to this, with other engines (if possible). Finally release the version `git tag -a v1.0.0`.

This setup helped me to use a single/duo Development environment for all types of development. And other environments for testing.